# Truffle Migrations Account Locked Error with --network command

Tags: go-ethereum, dapp-development, private-blockchain, contract-deployment, truffle

I have started a private blockchain using the command,

```
geth --networkid 1337 --datadir ~/home/xyz/testnet --ipcpath /home/xyz/.ethereum/geth.ipc --rpc --rpcapi eth,web3 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr localhost --rpccorsdomain "*";
```

Next, in another terminal console, I start the miner and unlock my test account,

```
> miner.start(1)
true


> personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.coinbase)
  Unlock account 0xSomeAddress
  Passphrase: 
  true
```

My truffle.js file contains the following,

```
module.exports = {
build: {
  "index.html": "index.html",
   "app.js": [
     "javascripts/app.js"
   ],
  "app.css": [
    "stylesheets/app.css"
   ],
  "images/": "images/"
},
networks: {
"staging": {
  network_id: 1337, 
  from: "0xAddress" // Unlocked Address
 }
},
rpc: {
  host: "localhost",
  port: 8545
 }
};
```

Finally, in another terminal, I run and compile the truffle application using,

```
truffle compile
truffle migrate --network staging
```

I get the below `Account locked Error` like below,

```
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  Migrations: 0xSomeAddress
Saving successful migration to network...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: account is locked
   at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ether-pudding/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
   at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ether-pudding/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:36
   at request.onreadystatechange (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:114:13)
   at dispatchEvent (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:591:25)
   at setState (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:610:14)
   at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:447:13)
   at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
   at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
   at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

Which part am I missing here? Is the process that I followed correct?
The same code runs sublimely on `testrpc` but not on this private blockchain, what essential part am I missing?

Please advice.

Comment: Please confirm . You ran the geth command in one terminal and unlocked account in another.

Comment: @A.K. Yes. I did unlock the account in another Terminal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possible it's not unlocked long enough?

```
web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3.personal.listAccounts[0],"password",15000); // 1st account, pw & time in seconds ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue but you may try to check the state of your account using `geth` itself, it did the trick for me.

When you are syncing/acting on the blockchain, `geth` uses a file for the Inter-process communication (IPC). Check what is that file on your case, something like:

`INFO [10-02|17:49:23] IPC endpoint opened: /Users/josealves/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc`

You can then "attach" `geth` to this by typing:

`geth attach /Users/josealves/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc`

You would then have a prompt where you can send commands to the blockchain and interact with the current session. By typing the `personal` command you can find the current state of your "wallet" of accounts:

```
{
  listAccounts: ["0xcb7fab56b707a54d17c791de41eaa9a399b3efef", "0x3a05b7c9f420f6b7c5f39ae29deab1352750bf26"],
  listWallets: [{
      accounts: [{...}],
      status: "Locked",
      url: (..)
  }, {
      accounts: [{...}],
      status: "Locked",
      url: (...)
  }],
```

There you'll get the current state of your account, and probably both of them are on the "Locked" state. You can then unlock them by typing:

`personal.unlockAccount('0x3a05b7c9f420f6b7c5f39ae29deab1352750bf26')`

You will then be asked for your account's password and it will be unlocked.

Afterwards it was ok to migrate.